# Intersection of two particular languages

Tags: formal-languages

Here's the question:

> Compute the intersection of the following two languages:
>   \begin{align}
> &L_1 = \{ a^{n+1} b^{2n} a^{n+1} \mid n \ge 0 \} \\
> &L_2 = \{ w \in \{a,b\}^* \mid \#_a(w) + \#_b(w) \equiv 1 \pmod 2 \}
> \end{align}

I'm pretty sure that $L_2$ is just "$|w|$ is odd", which would mean the intersection of the two languages would be $L_1$ when its length is odd, right?

What I'm confused about is that $|w|$ for every $w ∈ L1$ will always be even no matter what $n$ is.

Can someone help me find the solution? I have absolutely no clue how to do it.

Edit:  #a(w) + #b(w) %2 = 1 not 0 (my bad)

Comment: Actually, $L_2$ is the language of all words of *even* length.

Comment: Also, $|L_1| = \infty$. You mean "$|w|$ for every $w \in L_1$".

Answer (score 2):

$$L_1 = \{a^{n+1}b^{2n}a^{n+1} \mid n \ge 0\}$$

$$L_2 = \{w \mid (\#_a(w) + \#_b(w)) \bmod 2 = 1\}$$

I assume that $\#_a(w)$ means the number of $a$s in $w$.

First, I would write out some $w$ in $L_1$ and $L_2$:

$$L_1 = \{aa, aabbaa, aaabbbbaaa, \ldots\}$$

$$L_2 = \{a, b, aaa, aab, aba, abb, baa, bab, bba, bbb, aaaaa, \ldots\}$$

From this, we see that words in $L_1$ are always even length ($(n+1) + (2n) + (n+1) = 4n + 2 = 2(2n+1)$ and odd + even + odd = even) and words in $L_2$ are always odd length ($(a+b)\bmod2 = 1$).

This means $L_1 \cap L_2 = \emptyset$.

**Before OP's edit to post** ($L_2 = \{w \mid (\#_a(w) + \#_b(w)) \bmod 2 = 0\}$):

First, I would write out some $w$ in $L_1$ and $L_2$:

$$L_1 = \{aa, aabbaa, aaabbbbaaa, \ldots\}$$

$$L_2 = \{aa, ab, ba, bb, aaaa, aaab, aaba, \ldots\}$$

From this, we see that words in $L_1$ are always even length ($(n+1) + (2n) + (n+1) = 4n + 2 = 2(2n+1)$ and odd + even + odd = even) and words in $L_2$ are always even length ($(a+b)\bmod2 = 0$).

This means $L_1 \cap L_2 = L_1$ (because $L_1 \subset L_2$).